# Why am I getting &quot when using json_encode

Tags: php, json, laravel

Im returning some json

```
$keywords = Auth::user()->keywords;
return json_encode($keywords);
```

Its returning something like this.

```
{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;response&quot;:&quot;qwrewqrqw&quot;,&quot;alt_response&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;keyword&quot;:&quot;L0F3LZ&quot;,&quot;user_id&quot;:221,&quot;extra_charge&quot;:&quot;$0.00&quot;,&quot;campaign_id&quot;:0,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;DEMO&quot;,&quot;responses&quot;:0,&quot;next_billing_date&quot;:&quot;2017-10-24&quot;,&quot;status&quot;:&quot;active&quot;}
```

How can I get it to just return regular JSON.  I've never had this problem before.  It actually just suddenly started happening, and I only noticed it, because my JSON.parse($keywords)  failed.  So I console logged it, and got what you see above.

Any ideas?

My current workaround so far is to just do...

```
 var data = JSON.parse(keywords.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
```

Which works fine and gives me the object.  But...if one field contains a space, or line break, then this breaks.  How can I get regular old JSON instead of this &quot crap.

Comment: *"Why am I getting &quot when using json_encode"* You're not. Something else, subsequently, is running the JSON through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or similar (I'm guessing it's something automatic laravel is doing). The solution is to find that and not do so.

Comment: Why would it just start happening though??  I haven't changed any of my config in months.  Using Laravel.

Comment: Sounds like something auto-updated. :-|

Comment: Yeah, that would be the first thing I would think of.  But its not the case.  I have to run composer update in order to update anything.  Havent run that in months.  However....recently I did upgrade my PHP from 5.4 to 5.6.  But it was working a bit after I did that, so Im stumped.

Comment: How are you `echo`ing the JSON string to the view? If through Blade, `{{ }}` automatically escapes, try `{!! $your_json !!}`. The default behavior of `{{ }}` changed some versions ago, that's what might have happened to you.

Comment: Thank you!!!! that solved it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Blade, the default behavior is to escape the characters. So when you do

```
{{ $yourJSON }}
```

it's escaping the quotes, causing the problem your having. To avoid this, change it to

```
{!! $yourJSON !!}
```

so it won't escape it, and you won't have a problem parsing the JSON.

The default behavior changed in Laravel 5 (it previously didn't escape by default), which might be why you experienced this all of a sudden.

[Blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates)

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to handle new lines in JSON would you.  I feel like Ive tried everything.  Im nl2br() it in php.  So its storing in the databse with <br />.  Then when I retrieve it from php Im str_replacing("<br />" , "//n",$value).   JSON.parse still fails however, when trying to parse this

Comment: [{"id":1,"response":"qwrewqrqw\\n asdsw","alt_response":"","keyword":"L0F3LZ","user_id":221,"type":"DEMO","status":"active"}

Comment: Thats what its unable to parse

Comment: When I do it on JSfiddle, it works.  When I do it on my server. It fails.

Comment: I'm taking a look, just a second. It seems like there's a invisible unicode character that messes everything up. Paste the JSON [here](https://jsonlint.com), you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Yeah I know theres something wrong with it.  On the exact place where I hit enter.  What could it possibly be?  Im replacing the carriage returns with <br />  using nl2br().  Then when retrieving it Im converting those into //n.  I dont really see whats going wrong?  Its strange cuz in the DB, its getting replaced as <br />  but theres also clearly a carriage return.  If I delete that carriage return to make it just read   kjalkjsd<br/>lkjalskdj then is works.  But currently in the db it stores as kljlskdjs<br/>    (->cr)             jhkjhskdfds.   (->cr) just representing a new line

Comment: It's not where the new line is. The problem is definitely the invisible character. Try running [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ishegg/tvhabfkr/) in your computer, it should work.

Comment: Trust me, it's the invisible character, `\u200C`. See [here](https://3v4l.org/9LNjg). When I delete it in code, it's decoded correctly. Otherwise it returns `NULL`. So you can try that, replacing the character, but that certainly isn't a permanent solution. You need to try to figure out what's causing the extraneous character to be there in the first place!